# Use ruby parallel gem and pass variables to main

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, rubygems

I am trying to speed up with Parallel gem.
It works itself but I have a problem.
I want all nil to be overwrite test.
Or Array out have output.But result is nil.
How can I make it happen ?
I would like to have  some advise folks.

```
require 'parallel'

genes=[[1,nil],[2,nil],[3,nil],[4,nil],[5,nil],[6,nil],[7,nil],[8,nil]]
out =[]

Parallel.each(genes, in_threds: 4) do |g|

g[1] = "test"

out << g
end

p genes
p out
```

--RESULT---
[[1, nil], [2, nil], [3, nil], [4, nil], [5, nil], [6, nil], [7, nil], [8, nil]]
[]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have a typo in the "in_threads" portion of the Parallel command. Once I tried it with in_threads instead of in_threds, I got the output I believe you were expecting.

output expecting: [[1, "test"], [3, "test"], [2, "test"], [4, "test"], [5, "test"], [6, "test"], [8, "test"], [7, "test"]]

Comment: Can confirm. Coming a minute later ;)